# Fetchxml based SSRS Report Dynamics 365 9.0 error: Error: Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics

I have a FetchXML based SSRS Report Dynamics 365 9.0 .My dataset is valid XML and I can execute it in Fetchxml builder with desired results,
But when I run on a record I get the rsProcessingAborted  error with the following error on Event Viewer:
MSCRMReportingDataConnector:

```
Report data set execution failure. Error: Incorrect syntax near '<'.
```

I've Checked these:
Validated XML (Valid)
Run on FetchXML Builder: Valid Results
Opened on Report Builder and VS 2015 (no Error)
Checked "Similar" errors on google, not related , not worked

Comment: did you try a very simple query? did you try to exchange the quotes symbol? (if using double quotes switch to single quotes and viceversa)?

Comment: Thanks, but no, Changing to single quote results in an error prior to uploading the RDL file to reporting server about the format error.